# Clearing other ListView Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do I clear the selection in other ListView properly? For example I have 4 list views stacked, and if I have a selection in listView1, then I select a new item in listView2, I want the selection in listView1 to be gone and the item in listview2 is selected properly. Note: the list view is single selection.

```
<StackPanel>
   <ListView x:Name="listView1" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView2" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView3" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView4" />
</StackPanel>
```

I first tried:

```
<StackPanel>
   <ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged1" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView2" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged2" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView3" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged3" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView4" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged4" />
</StackPanel>
```

code behind:

```
private void selectionChanged1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listView2.SelectedItem = null;
    listView3.SelectedItem = null;
    listView4.SelectedItem = null;
}
private void selectionChanged2(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.SelectedItem = null;
    listView3.SelectedItem = null;
    listView4.SelectedItem = null;
}
...
```

The problem I am having is that after having a selection in listView1 and click an item in listView2, the selection in listView1 is cleared, but the item in listView2 is not selected.

The reason is because there are (at least) 2 events fired:

1. selectionchanged2 fired, claring selections in listview 1,3,4
2. because I am clearing selection in listview1, selectionchanged1 is also fired, which clears selections in listview 2,3,4
3. I think selectionchanged2 is fired again.
4. Therefore I ended up with no selection in any list.

Do you have better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may try to use this *SelectionChanged* event for all your *ListViews*:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        if (listView1 != sender as ListView) listView1.SelectedItem = null;
        if (listView2 != sender as ListView) listView2.SelectedItem = null;
        if (listView3 != sender as ListView) listView3.SelectedItem = null;
        if (listView4 != sender as ListView) listView4.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

It just check if there is something new set in *ListView*, if so, then clear all other *ListViews*.

Comment: This works beautifully! So the second SelectionChanged will not alter anything because the clearing item is e.AddedItems.Count == 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you set a ListView's SelectedItem to null the SelectionChanged event will fire again because a ListView's SelectedItem was changed, so you can use a flag to skip the second SelectionChanged even call.

Check the below code snippet. I Hope it will be of help to you.

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel">
            <ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <ListView x:Name="listView2" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 4</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <ListView x:Name="listView3" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListViewItem>Item 5</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 6</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <ListView x:Name="listView4" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListViewItem>Item 7</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 8</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code-behind

```
namespace ListView
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool skipSelectionChanged;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (skipSelectionChanged)
            {
                skipSelectionChanged = false;

                return;
            }

            var listView = sender as ListView;

            if (listView != null)
            {
                var name = listView.Name;
                for (int i = 0; i < MyStackPanel.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    var child = MyStackPanel.Children[i] as ListView;
                    if (child.Name != name && child.SelectedItem != null)
                    {
                        skipSelectionChanged = true;
                        child.SelectedItem = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at one point it works, but there is also a time where I have selection on two listviews with your solution.

Comment: yes I see that issue, I'll try to fix the code and update my post

Comment: @kurakura88, I've fixed the issue and updated my post and it works fine now, please check my update

Comment: Yes, it does work now. Thanks for contributing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: Link them all to the same handler, such as:

```
<StackPanel>
   <ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView2" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView3" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged" />
   <ListView x:Name="listView4" SelectionChanged="selectionchanged" />
</StackPanel>
```

and then:

```
private void selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string listViewName = ((ListView)sender).Name;
    if (listViewName == "listView1")
    {
        listView2.SelectedItem = null;
        listView3.SelectedItem = null;
        listView4.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    else if (listViewName == "listView3")
    {
        listView1.SelectedItem = null;
        listView2.SelectedItem = null;
        listView4.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    else if (listViewName == "listView4")
    {
        listView1.SelectedItem = null;
        listView2.SelectedItem = null;
        listView3.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    else if (listViewName == "listView2")
    {
        listView1.SelectedItem = null;
        listView3.SelectedItem = null;
        listView4.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

It is messy and long (and untested), but let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, not working, reason is similar, the event is fired 3 times from 2 different senders, clearing all the listview selections. I am thinking to put the control/ handler on the StackPanel... so that the event is fired once, but... there is no SelectionChanged event handler in StackPanel... so I am still clueless.

Comment: You might as well just handle the `Click` event. That at least ensures the event only fires once every time you click another listView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a null check before clearing other fields like

For listView1:

```
private void selectionChanged1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(listView1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        listView2.SelectedItem = null;
        listView3.SelectedItem = null;
        listView4.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can change it for others.

Comment: Sorry, it does not even clear anything. listView1.SelectedItem is not null when the event is fired.d